# Should similar questions be closed because they are exact duplicates?

Tags: discussion, closing, exact-duplicates

> **Exact duplicate of:**
>   [Should different questions that yield similar/duplicate answers be closed?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/951/should-different-questions-that-yield-similar-duplicate-answers-be-closed)

Comment: +1 for recursion