# Highly Upvoted Question is in its essense a duplicate of another Question

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

In [As a queen, what must I do to take the son of my husband's dynasty out of succession line?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/322080/as-a-queen-what-must-i-do-to-take-the-son-of-my-husbands-dynasty-out-of-succes/322082?noredirect=1#comment458870_322082)  the OP inquires on how to eliminate one specific son from succession.

In [How do I prevent my imbecile son from being an heir?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/104439/how-do-i-prevent-my-imbecile-son-from-being-an-heir?rq=1) the OP also requests to know how to eliminate one specific son from succession.

[Can I disown my heir?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92096/can-i-disown-my-heir) asks the very same thing

While it's true that they involve slightly different motives, they can be summed up to "*How can I prevent one of my sons from inheriting?*"

If the question was about any character other than a son, it would have a different scenario (and as such answers), but since all of them share the same answer, they would be considered duplicates.(?)

However, those answers are all on 40+,30+, and 15+ upvotes. What exactly should we do about it?

Comment: *but since all of them share the same answer, they would be considered duplicates* - 2 different questions with the same answer doesn't make the questions duplicates

Comment: The questions ask exactly for the same thing, albeit with different things originating the need for the solution. In its core they're the same, and so are the answers.

Comment: All 3 seem to be different scenarios.  All 3 questions may have 1 shared answer, but possible that alternative answers could apply to only 1 of these 3 scenarios.

Comment: how come? "I want to open door X because..." (Scenario 1) "I want to go from A to B, (Scenario 2) "I want to go from B to A", (Scenario 3) I don't like closed doors.

All of them ask to open the same door.

Comment: See: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/956/101016

Comment: @camelCase "How do I kill my (*) son?", where * can be "Imbecile, non-dinastic or just unwanted. But the question is the same, how do I kill my son

Comment: Well none seem to be asking how to kill a son.  1 is specific to removing a child from the succession line onto another child from another line, 1 is asking how to promote another child above the eldest and the other child is a generic question asking if it is possible to disown an heir.  As already said, there may be 1 answer that covers all 3 questions but still possible for other answers that are specific to 1 or 2 of these 3 sample questions.

Answer (score 3):

If you think a question is a duplicate of another, vote to close it as such. A question's score has no bearing on whether it's a duplicate or not.